# Обобщающий класс

Tags: c#

У меня есть 3 класса, допустим

```
public class Person
{
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public string Surname {get;set;}

 public Person (strin name, string surname)
 {
  Name = name;
  Surname = surname;
 }
}

public class Address
{
 public string Street {get;set;}
 public string House{get;set;}

 public Person (strin street, string house)
 {
  Street  = street;
  House = house;
 }
}

public class Phone
{
 public string Number {get;set;}

 public Person (strin number)
 {
  Number  = number;
 }
}
```

и нужно сделать 4й обобщающий класс, куда должны быть занесены данные с этих 3х классов и поле Email. Второй день ломаю голову как их объединить, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: В приведенном коде имя конструктора класса отличается от имени класса для всех кроме класса Person. Если это опечатка - исправьте пожалуйста в вопросе, если нет, то исправьте в вашем коде, в таком виде не скомпилируется

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> и поле Email

Думаю, что всё-таки свойство (а это разные вещи)

Если я правильно понял, что такое "обобщающий класс", то так:

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public Person Person { get; }

    public Address Address { get; }

    public Phone Phone { get; }

    public string Email { get; }

    public UserInfo(Person person, Address address, Phone phone, string email)
    {
        Person = person;
        Address = address;
        Phone = phone;
        Email = email;
    }
}
```

Comment: да спасибо, вроде как оно, настолько все просто.